# XSLT for dynamic tree

Tags: xslt

You can see my xml patern sample below. Every **manuel** has **chapter** tags, **chapter** tags may have **subchapter** and **checklist** tags. There is no static depth, it may change document to document, so I couldnt write the dynamic recursive xslt code to generate Html. Does anyone knows, how can I achive this.

```
  <manuel name="Test">
    <chapter name="00">

      <subchapter name="00.01">
        <checklist  name="00.01.01">
          <summary>abc</summary>
        </checklist>
      </subchapter>

      <subchapter name="00.02">
           <checklist  name="00.02.01">
               <summary>def</summary>
           </checklist>
           <subchapter name="00.02.02">
                <checklist  name="00.02.02.01">
                    <summary>xyz</summary>
                </checklist>
           </subchapter>
      </subchapter>

      <checklist  name="00.03">
            <summary>ZZZZ</summary>
      </checklist>
    </chapter>
  </manuel>
```

For this sample, I suppose this result. I can set the css style, its not important now. The problem is generating the structure.

```
<div class="cssChapter"> 00</div>
<div class="cssSubChapter"> 00.01 </div>
<div class="cssCheckList"> 00.01.01 </div>
<div class="cssSummary"> abc </div>      
<div class="cssSubChapter"> 00.02 </div>
<div class="cssCheckList"> 00.02.01 </div>
<div class="cssSummary"> def </div>      
<div class="cssSubChapter"> 00.02.02 </div>   
<div class="cssCheckList"> 00.02.02.01 </div>   
<div class="cssSummary"> xyz </div>      
<div class="cssCheckList"> 00.03 </div>      
<div class="cssSummary"> ZZZZ</div>
```

Comment: What is your output supposed to look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the supposed result but the important point is genereting structure.

Comment: To re-ask @KimHomann's question. Is this a text/csv/xml/html/other output?

Comment: I need to get Html output

Comment: I updated the response part

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple apply-templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="manuel">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <div class="cssChapter">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subchapter">
    <div class="cssSubChapter">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="checklist">
    <div class="cssChecklist">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="summary">
    <div class="cssSummary">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ3915/1.

Comment: This code Works good but I need to get all the summary tags content with copy-of . I cant reach the summary tags content. I gues because of  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[@name]"/>   How should I change this definition. I forgat to add summary tag to output, I added now.

Comment: I have edited the code sample, it now simply processes all descendant elements with `.//*` and the stylesheet has a template for `summary` elements.